# NSPredicate filter for search bar

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I am using a `NSPredicate` filter method to filter my search bar but its not returning back with anything. `profileNameLabel` is a label from a cell that is incorporated within my table view. I want to be able to search letters or words that matches texts that is displayed in the `profileNameLabel` but nothing is appearing. I don't think `profileNameLabel` is recognised properly by the `NSPredicate` filter. am I missing more code? Im fairly new to swift help would be much appreciated. thanks

Down below I've pasted my code(using swift 3, xcode8)

```
func filterTableView(ind:Int,text:String) {
        switch ind {  
        case selectedScope.Name.rawValue:  
        intialProfiles.filter(using: NSPredicate(format: "profileNameLabel contains[c] %@", text))
        self.searchTableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: What is `initialProfiles`?  Do the objects in that array have a property `profileNameLabel`?

Comment: with the predicate you perform it on the source not UI

Comment: var intialProfiles = NSMutableArray() -this array is made up off data retrieved from firebase which consists off a profileName, Country etc. I have  also called func filterTableView in my func searchBar